# how can i create an arrayadapter in asynctask. onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

   veriAdaptoru=new ArrayAdapter<String>
      (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, a);
   liste=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
   liste.setAdapter(veriAdaptoru);      
}
```

i have to write this code but in this part i get error

```
(veriAdaptoru=new ArrayAdapter<String>
           (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, a);)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, a);`
you must load `context` from Activity, but if you write `this` in onPostExecute it is another. Make in you Activity class some variable

```
Context context = MyActivity.this;
```

if your AsyncTask is in another class - create constructor and pass context from Activiy in it.
and then you can do

```
 (context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, a);`
```